# User Defined Class as a Template Parameter

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, std, stdmap

I' m re-implementing `std::map`. I need to make sure that **any data type (basic or user defined) key** will work with it. I declared the Map class as a template which has two parameters for the key and the value. My question is if I need to use a string as the key type, **how can I overload the < and > operators for string type keys only??** In template specialization we have to specialize the whole class with the type we need as I understand it.
Is there any way I can do this in a better way?? What if I add a separate Key class and use it as the template type for Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should factor out the comparison as a type, like the normal `std::map` does. That is, have a utility class `less_compare`:

```
template <typename T>
struct less_compare
{
    bool operator()(const T& pLhs, const T& pRhs) const
    {
        return pLhs < pRhs;
    }
};
```

And then:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare = less_compare<Key> >
class map
{
    // ...

private:
    Compare mCompare;
};
```

And to compare two values, do: `if (mCompare(someThing, someOtherThing))`, which will be true with `someThing` is "less than" `someOtherThing`. Note this factoring also allows user-defined comparisons (which is why "less than" is quoted). This is known as policy-based design.

And now you can specialize just the `less_compare` class for C-strings. (And also provide `greater_compare` and kin.)

---

Do keep in mind, unless this is for learning, you should not be implementing your own map. Also note that `std::string` has `operator<` overloaded already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate reply, and yes it is for learning purposes. I'm new to templates so I wanted to get my hands a bit dirty :D

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but why shouldn't we be implementing our own maps??

Comment: @isurulucky: Since you're doing it for practice, it's okay. But in general you shouldn't waste time with something that's already done. (If you need a map include `<map>` and use `std::map`.) Especially since things that are already done have been (and are) heavily optimized and tested.

Comment: Hi I did what you said. It worked well so far. But when I change the code of () overload,  to work with a user defined object (say a struct with an integer in it), I get some link errors again, saying operator () is already defined. What is the matter here??
PS : I have used include guards as well.

Comment: @isurulucky: I'd start a new question with that. Make sure you include all the relevant code.

Comment: @GMan: Ok, did it just now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [type traits](http://www.drdobbs.com/184404270;jsessionid=ALPQZS1XTU4DPQE1GHOSKH4ATMY32JVN). It will give you a framework to solve also the possible future differences between types.