# Can we pass user defined data type to template as argument

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ is there a way where we can pass user defined argument to a template.

Suppose there is a template class as below:

```
template <Class T>
class Stack
{
    // .....
}

int main()
{
    Stack<employee>; // here employee needs to be obj of a class
}
```

Can someone please explain with example or guide me to some links that talk about this.

Thanks so much

Comment: If you couldn't do this, templates would be pretty limiting in their usefulness don't you think, plus it would defeat the original design principle of templates if you couldn't use user-defined types

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871055/user-defined-class-as-a-template-parameter

Comment: I agree but need to know how this can be done with example.

Comment: But your basic code snippet is no different to `vector< employee >` in it's usage, there is nothing complicated here

Comment: "employee needs to be obj of a class" - no, it will have to be a class (or other type) not an object, to match the template's type parameter. Your introductory book should cover templates in detail (and also explain that `main` needs to return `int` not `void`).

Answer (score 1):

C++ templates generally work on types, or sometimes integral values. Since you have an object, and not a type, you can't pass it to the template.

You can however, use `decltype` from C++11 onwards to go backwards from an object to its type. So for example, if you had used `auto widget = someObject.someMethod();` and didn't have `widget`'s type to hand, but wanted a `std::vector` of them, you could use `std::vector<decltype(widget)> x;` to create a vector that holds objects of whatever type `widget` had.

Answer (score -2):

No, template parameter should be a type name (e.g. Class, struct, built-in types etc.) in general cases. It can't be a object of class type. Though in some special cases, it can be variable/value of int type

I would suggest you to do some reading to better understand templates
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part
http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/

Comment: User defined data type means class, struct, union or enum